# ul element as price-list; same position to start for the prices

Tags: html, css

I want to list something in an `<ul>`-tag.
Something like

```
<ul>
<li>Milk: 1.29$</li>
<li>Pepper: 12.55$</li>
<li>butter: 3.7$</li>
</ul>
```

I want to start the prices at the same position. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried, and why are you not using a `table` for a price table? And why should the prices start at the same position? The normal practice is to make them right-aligned, for better comparability.

Comment: I tried a similiar idea, but I wanted to set a margin-right. I thought that a list is semanticaly nearer. I thought, that of it as a price list.

Answer (score 6):

You could add a `<span>` to wrap the item and apply a width to the `<span>`. Alternatively you could use a table as this is tabular data.

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3URPX/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Milk:</span> 1.29$</li>
    <li><span>Pepper:</span> 12.55$</li>
    <li><span>butter:</span> 3.7$</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    display: block;
}
ul li span {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```